# Is half-in half-out hyphenated?

Tags: hyphenation

Do you hyphenate half-in half-out? He was half-in half-out. (of the window). Or half in, half out? Sheesh, nothing coming up on google. Any ideas/help please?

Comment: I'd use "half-in, half-out" or "half in, half out".  But [Ngram](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22half%20in%20half%20out%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1987,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) finds all imaginable variations.

Answer (score -2):

I see no reason for hyphens.  Then, again, I see no reason for many apostrophes in today's names, but there they are.  (Saw one recently, Rickey la' Davis--really?!)

Comment: Okay thanks. In that case, if no obvious rule, I might go for hyphens cos I prefer how it looks to the comma. I like my words to look neat too! Don't know Rickey la Davis I'm afraid. Footballer Rickey L Davis? In which case please explain the la part... thanks.

Comment: No reasons for hyphens in general or in this specific case?

Answer (score -2):

No hyphens, because "half in" and "half out" aren't words.  Hyphens connect the parts of a compound word.  The stress on the last part of each, "in" and "out", is a clue that these are phrases, not words.  Compound words usually have stress on the first part of the compound.

You could add a comma after "half in" to clarify the structure, if you wanted.

Comment: If you do the hokey pokey, you’re doing the hokey-pokey dance. The hyphens tie the words together, so that the hokey-pokey dance is distinguishable from (say) a hokey dance being done in the pokey.

Comment: @GlobalCharm, You could say the same about 'the George Foreman grill", but it still doesn't need a hyphen (because "George Foreman" is not a word of English).

Comment: "... imagine a floor-warping, ceiling-spinning, brain-churning, think-you're-gonna-die-and-afraid-you-might-not hangover" ((Kristin Chenoweth) probably has emphasis on the 'not'. Compounding is poorly regulated, and 'half-in-half-out' seems a better candidate than the above (rather famous) example.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. I'd agree that three hyphens are better than two here. "Half-in-half-out" is a composite expression. You could say someone was "half-in" the window, and equally one could say they were "half-out", but used in tandem they express a single idea.

Comment: @Greg Lee Names for a single individual are not normally included. as regards hyphenating rules for pre-posiotioned composite adjectives. However, if one speaks about the Duckworth-Lewis rules for calculating the target score in a rain-affected, limited-overs cricket match - a hyphen becomes appropriate as you are talking about two separate people Mr Duckworth and Mr Lewis. It is sometimes known as the Duckworth-Lewis-Stern method. However the Webb Ellis rules in rugby stand without a hyphen since William Webb Ellis was a single person.